# How do I write to a file?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, file-io

I'm having a problem in windows phone 7 that I couldn't find answer for it.
I'm trying to write something from a textbox to a simple txt file that I have in my project files. I tried to use StreamWriter but only StreamReader works,I tread to use IsolatedStorage but again it didn't work.
So please,maybe you can find me the solution for this problem?

EDIT: 
code that I used:

```
var myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
// Specify the file path and options.
using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("/Discount%20it;component/Tax.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, myStore))
{
    //Write the data
    using (var isoFileWriter = new StreamWriter(isoFileStream))
    {
        isoFileWriter.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
    }
}

string fileName = "/Discount%20it;component/Tax.txt";

using (var isoStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    // we need to check to see if the file exists
    if (!isoStorage.FileExists(fileName))
    {
        // file doesn't exist...time to create it.
        isoStorage.CreateFile(fileName);
    }

    // since we are appending to the file, we must use FileMode.Append
    using (var isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append, isoStorage))
    {
        // opens the file and writes to it.
        using (var fileStream = new StreamWriter(isoStream))
        {
            fileStream.Write(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code you used and explain "didn't work" - did it crash, or produce an error, or fail silently, or what?

Comment: @Jason sometimes it said that I don't have premmision,IsolatedStorage exceptions,StreamWriter exceptions...

Comment: Spend a second correctly formatting your code.  It helps you get answers.

Answer (score 0):

There's a section on msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626519%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) that explains it. Does this not work?

Example code shown on that page:

```
private void btnWrite_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Obtain the virtual store for the application.
    IsolatedStorageFile myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

    // Create a new folder and call it "MyFolder".
    myStore.CreateDirectory("MyFolder");

    // Specify the file path and options.
    using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("MyFolder\\myFile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, myStore))
    {
        //Write the data
        using (var isoFileWriter = new StreamWriter(isoFileStream))
        {
            isoFileWriter.WriteLine(txtWrite.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you'll note that you need to programmatically create a directory in the isolated storage before you attempt to write a file to it.

For development purposes the directory and file will be created on your development machine in a directory as shown on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx). If you're developing on a Windows 7 machine I'd expect that you'll find your isolated directory and file in the same location as Vista e.g. for a non-roaming user profile `Users<username>AppData\Local`.

so for the above code your file should be in `<username>\AppData\Local\MyFolder`.

This line in the code:

```
IsolatedStorageFile myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
```

Maps your IsolatedStorage to `<username>\AppData\Local` on the dev machine and calls it `myStore`.

This line creates a directory there that you can then write to:

```
myStore.CreateDirectory("MyFolder");
```

To have your application read from this file here's example code:

```
// This code opens and reads the contents of myFile.txt.
private void btnRead_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Obtain a virtual store for the application.
    IsolatedStorageFile myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

    try
    {
        // Specify the file path and options.
        using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("MyFolder\\myFile.txt", FileMode.Open, myStore))
        {
            // Read the data.
            using (var isoFileReader = new StreamReader(isoFileStream))
            {
                txtRead.Text = isoFileReader.ReadLine();
            }
        }

    }
    catch
    {
        // Handle the case when the user attempts to click the Read button first.
        txtRead.Text = "Need to create directory and the file first.";
    }
}
```

Notice how you have to get the actual location of the Isolated Storage file again and that you include the directory name in the file path when opening your file.

**Additional (1/3/2012)**

When using `FileMode.Append` ensure that you also use `FileAccess.Write`.
Instead of checking to see if a file exists just use `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`.
If using Silverlight ensure that isolated storage is enabled:

```
Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft Silverlight -> Microsoft Silverlight -> Application Storage -> make sure the 'enable application storage' checkbox is checked.
```

Comment: I modified the code so that it fit my project:
 using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("\\Tax.txt", FileMode.Create, myStore))
 isoFileWriter.Write(textBox1.Text);
               
but still nothing happened,the file Tax.txt is in the projects file(where is the mainpage.xaml)

Comment: As I understand it you need to create a directory for your file first as this ensures that data files are isolated between applications.

Comment: I created a directory in my project named "Files" and now when i'm trying to do what you gave me(without creating the new directory) it gives me this error - Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.

Comment: IsolatedStorage is separate from your program's executables and resources.  You cannot write directly to a file that is part of your application.

Comment: So how I do it? Because now I can read from the file. And I just want to have A simple txt file that I would be able to read and write to it.

Comment: Firstly thanks,but I don't want to create the file and the folder every time that someone open's the application I want it to be created only once.

Comment: Once you create it in IsolatedStorage it will stay there.  The first time your app runs you probably need to read the file from your app's resources and then make a writable copy in IsolatedStorage.

Comment: See my updates. During development testing you should be able to access your file directly at the location mentioned in your AppData\Local\Discount directory. Note that system path environment variables should not be used in declaring the path name.

Comment: I tried to do what you told be but I still get this - Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.
here - var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Files\\Tax.txt", FileMode.Create, myStore

Comment: So you called:     myStore.CreateDirectory("Files"); before running     var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Files\\Tax.txt", FileMode.Create, myStore) ?

Comment: Yes.
I added FileAccess.Write but still,it throws me this - Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.

Answer (score 0):

Files that are distributed as part of the xap are not (easily) modified.

Typically, if you have some data that you want to update and keep in a file, you should do that in IsolatedStorage.

Assuming that you ship the default data in a file as part of the XAP, you'll want to do the following:

When wanting to read the data:
- check if the file in IsolatedStorage exists.
-- If it does then read from there.
-- If it does not then read from the file that ships with the XAP

When wanting to write the data:
- write it to IsolatedStorage and overwrite any existing file/data.

Comment: But how I access to it? I mean if i create a file it automaticlly connected to my application? And again it allways telling me this - Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream. here - var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Files\\Tax.txt", FileMode.Create, myStore